# Instalando Qt no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015

Gostaria de saber como instalar o QT no visual studio 2015, fiz de tudo, porém não consigo utilizar o mesmo. Sempre que dou um #include  por exemplo, fala que não existe o arquivo ou diretório. Já tentei de várias formas.
Qual a melhor forma para se utilizar o QT?

Comment: Espero que na versão seguinte do Qt5.x, já tenham resolvido esse problema de reconhecimento do VS2015!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas o QT5.6 suporta o VS2015, mas ele ainda esta em versão RC (*Release Candidate*), pode experimentar, mas versões RC estão sujeitas a BUGs, mesmo estando próximo ao lançamento, segue os downloads:

- http://download.qt.io/development_releases/qt/5.6/5.6.0-rc/

Já as **versões estáveis** do QT5 suportam apenas suporta o *VS 2010*, *VS 2012* e *VS 2013* (este ultimo suporta 32bit e 64bit), ou seja provavelmente tentou usar uma destas versões, mas o VS2015 não as reconhece.

Pra instalar o QT com VisualStudio siga estes passos:

Primeiro selecione a versão desejada:

- QT para VS2013 64bit: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.5.1.exe
- QT para VS2013 32bit: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.5.1.exe

Depois instale o VisualStudio2013, no caso existe a versão comunitária que é "free":

- https://www.visualstudio.com/post-download-vs?sku=community&clcid=0x409

Agora **o mais importante** (que geralmente esquecemos), instale o **VS Add-in** pra QT5 (compatível pra qualquer versão do QT5.x.x incluindo o QT5.6-rc):

- http://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/qt-vs-addin-1.2.5.exe

Depois disso você poderá usar o QT pelo VisualStudio diretamente e até importar projetos do `.pro` e usa em `.sln`:

> [image: VS com QT]

Eu pessoalmente prefiro o "QT Creator" pra desenvolver, mas tanto o VS quanto o Qtcreator irão atender as suas necessidades, então não tem uma melhor forma de usar, você escolhe conforme você se sentir mais acostumado.